# Query on protecting passwords in property file in java stand alone applications

Tags: java

We are having website which is hosted in real time server
we have developed a  swing application through which we are connecting our remote database of our website .This application also provides feature to upload files to our website from the system like picassa software.Now we are planing to place this application in our website so that others can download and use it.

If I do like that others may extract my .exe file to jar file.May see the property file and can get database and ftp client passwords.So how should I provide security for my property file.

How softwares like picassa is protecting their passwords from us.
Please give an idea about these questions  so that we can further proceed.

Thanks in advance ,

Answer (score 1):

Does your website with the remote database have an application server that is serving the web content?  If not, what is the database for?

If so, you should write a [REST service](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/giepu.html) or [web service](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/bnayl.html) that the Swing application communicates with, so that all database connections are made from the application server to the database, not from your Swing application directly to the database.  This has multiple benefits: apart from security, which you have already outlined, there is much less latency between the application server and the database than between your Swing application and the database.  Furthermore, it gives you the opportunity to encapsulate business logic on the server and reuse code from your web application, thus extracting it from the Swing application.

Of course, you then need to secure the service itself.  To do that, you can use a user authentication system like [Spring Security](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/) to ensure that only certain users can access your service.  This typically takes the form of a login API that establishes an ephemeral session token, and then all subsequent requests to the service supply that token to the service in a header (SOAP header, HTTP header, whatever).

For the FTP requirement, you could do this on the service side as well, although you would be transferring potentially large files to your server just to upload them to an FTP site.  Alternatively, if feasible, you could have different usernames and passwords for your different users, and make then enter their credentials before being able to FTP their content.  Then there is no shared FTP password and you do not have to worry about exposing it.